# Identifying $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X)\cong \mathbb{R}[Y]$ intuitively (and formally). Also showing $(X)$ is not a maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to wrap my head around $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X)$. I know this means that $$\bar{X} = 0,$$ where $\bar{X} = X + (X)$. Now, perhaps naively, I would proceed as follows: $$ f(X,Y)\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]\mapsto \bar{f} = f(0,Y) + (X) \in \mathbb{R}[Y]. $$

Now, the real reason I'm thinking about this is because I'm asked to show that $(X)$ is not a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. I thought I do that by showing that $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X)$ is not a field.

By the reasoning above we'd have $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X)\cong\mathbb{R}[Y]$, which *is* a field. Hence I'm sure it's not right.

---

Edit: of course, $\mathbb{R}[Y]$ *isn't* a field (quick proof: suppose $Yf(Y)=1$ for $f\in\mathbb{R}[Y]\backslash\{0\} $, evaluating at $Y=0$ gives $0=1$).

Furthermore, the identification $f(X,Y)\mapsto f(0,Y)$ *is* correct, and gives a morphism to prove the above mentioned isomorphism using the isomorphism theorems. And since $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X)\cong \mathbb{R}[Y]$ isn't a field, $(X)$ is not maximal in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[Y]$ is not a field. What is the inverse of $Y$, or $Y+1$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven wow, I must be really tired! Of course $\mathbb{R}[Y]$ isn't a field. Could you tell me if my identification of the quotient ring was correct in the first place? I'm still not quite convinced... If it is, then I have shown $(X)$ cannot be a maximal ideal.

Comment: Edit: I am convinced now that my initial idea was indeed correct. $f(X,Y)\mapsto f(0,Y)$ and hence $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]\cong \mathbb{R}[Y]$.

Comment: Yes, it works. You are better using the map in the comment $f(X,Y)\mapsto f(0,Y)$, noting that it has kernel $(X)$, and that way you don't have to deal with $f(0,Y)+(X)$.